# Parsing wavefront obj file consists of polygons in three.js

Tags: three.js, wavefront

In my 3D object; I have several boxes like;

[image]
But if I try to load and display [obj](http://www.ugurbaltaci.com/obj/Deneme.obj) and [mtl](http://www.ugurbaltaci.com/obj/Deneme.mtl) file with three.js, 5-sided or more-sided objects not loaded properly ( like below ) . Then; I discover that three.js supports only 3-sided or 4-sided faces.

Is there any solution to divide these faces in object file and load them ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to triangulate your model before exporting it. Most 3D editors out there have this option. Some editors have that as option in the OBJ exporter options. If that's not an option you can make a copy/backup of the model, triangulate that, export then delete/hide.