# Three.js + .OBJ loading : triangular faces only?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

This will concerns only polygonals faces (object's faces with more than 4 edges)..

In 3DSMAX there are 3 exporting modes for .OBJ : Triangles, Quads and Polygons.
I've made many tests and get the same results with the two available workflows (importing .obj with OBJLoader and importing .js via convert_obj_three.py) :

- polygons are not supported [(see this image)](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=440017polygonal.jpg)
- quads is ok for most polygonals objects, but three.js generates additionnals parasites faces onto some of them

The best result is obtained by setting export to Triangles mode (and thus to export heavier models), is it a known problem ?

Comment: It seems that more people are having your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342093/

Comment: I didn't see it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a known problem, but rather something threejs just doesn't do. In 3d it's easier to deal with triangles than quads or polygons. I'm not 100% sure, you might want to check on [github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/)

Comment: Thanks. Default 3DSMAX setting is Quads (in my version), so it can be usefull to remind ..